# Cannot get exact Hour using Laravel's Carbon

Tags: php, oop, date, laravel, php-carbon

I'm inserting date and time data in the database, my datatype is timestamp, I am inserting data using carbon but I always get this output from it  '2014-11-25 00:53:48' I always get 00 on the hours, been stuck here for three hours... here is my code

```
           $mydate=Carbon::now();
            DB::table('attendances')
            ->where('user_id', Input::get('empid'))
            ->update(array('logon' =>$mydate));
```

Answer (score 1):

try using `$mydate->format("H:i")`

Carbon defaults to outputting in DateTime format.

Also this looks like a simple use case: You could use DB::raw('NOW()') in place of $mydate if you are using MySQL

```
DB::table('attendances')
    ->where('user_id', Input::get('empid'))
    ->update(array('logon' =>DB::raw('NOW()')));
```

EDIT:
Also worth noting that Carbon extends php's DateTime. That means all DateTime functionality is still there. It also means your problem could be stemming from a problem with your PHP installation/configuration.

Comment: fixed the proble, all I did was to add +8 to the time, I'll post the answer

Comment: Sounds like your TimeZone isn't set in PHP then. :)